# NM_TREEVIEW* of tree control

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I am dealing with [NM_TREEVIEW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa932730.aspx), where from above structure i am only concentrate on itemNew.lParam.

For example,

```
  void CCtrlDlgTree::OnSelChangedTreeCtrl(
        NMHDR* pNMHDR, 
        LRESULT* pResult
        ) 
    {
        NM_TREEVIEW* pNMTreeView = (NM_TREEVIEW*)pNMHDR;
            pNMTreeView->itemNew.lParam;
     }
```

In above example i am getting correct pointer of **NM_TREEVIEW**. But when i apply same logic for below function

```
void CCtrlModDefDlgTree::OnNMRClick(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
{
    NM_TREEVIEW* pNMTreeView = (NM_TREEVIEW*)pNMHDR;
    pNMTreeView->itemNew.lParam;
}
```

I getting garbage value of **NM_TREEVIEW** pointer.

Please help me how to access NM_TREEVIEW in OnNMRClick or how access pNMTreeView->itemNew in OnNMRClick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your said you want lParam of Tree node in following function,

```
void CCtrlModDefDlgTree::OnNMRClick(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
{
    NM_TREEVIEW* pNMTreeView = (NM_TREEVIEW*)pNMHDR;
    pNMTreeView->itemNew.lParam;
}
```

It is impossible as per me to retrive lParam from *pNMHDR. But if you successfully getting HTREEITEM in this function then you can easily get lParam like in following Example,

```
 CCtrlModDefDlgTree::OnNMRClick(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
 {
        // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
         /* Get the cursor position for this message */ 
        DWORD dwPos = GetMessagePos(); 
        /* Convert the co-ords into a CPoint structure */ 
        CPoint pt( GET_X_LPARAM( dwPos ), GET_Y_LPARAM ( dwPos ) ); 
        CPoint spt; 
        spt = pt; 
        /* convert to screen co-ords for the hittesting to work */ 
        ScreenToClient( &spt ); 
        UINT test; 
        HTREEITEM hti = HitTest( spt, &test ); 
        TVITEM tvi;
       tvi.hItem = hti;
       tvi.mask = TVIF_PARAM;
       TreeView_GetItem(GetSafeHwnd(),&tvi);    
  }
```

And from **TVITEM*** you easily get lParam of tree node.

Answer (score 3):

If what you are trying to achieve is displaying context menu, here is the KB article for you:

[How To Display a Context Menu for CTreeCtrl (KB222905)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/222905)

As for the code, this cast:

`NM_TREEVIEW* pNMTreeView = (NM_TREEVIEW*)pNMHDR;`

looks incorrect, as "Right Click" notification message does not send NM_TREEVIEW structure as lParam, but just NMHDR structure.

Answer (score 0):

Just read the docks. NM_RCLICK does not give you a pointer to a treeview item!

It is just a pointer to NMHDR!
Just read the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773484%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

It may be easier if you use WM_RBUTTONDOWN and determine the item hit by yourself (use [TVM_HITTEST](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773732%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))